# Hidden TextArea Copies to Clickboard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to setup a page that has a list of buttons, in colums (signatures, returns, inquiries, etc). Currently the text is built in to the textarea feature, see:

```
<td>
  <b>PartSelect</b>
  <br />
  <textarea id="copyTarget" 
            cols="25"
            rows="3">Customer Service&#10;www.partselect.com&#10;888-895-1535
  </textarea>
  <br />
  <button id="copyButton">Copy</button>
</td>
```

Once I get this portion of the code figured out, I will be pulling the textarea value from the MySQL database, but I can do that. Right now, I am trying to use `style:hidden;` which does hide the text area, but loses the copy function. The Javascript function code is below:

```
document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget"), "msg");
});
```

As I said, this works when the field is visible, however stops working when I hide the textarea. Is there a solution to this?

For reference, if neccesary, the table in MySQL uses the following information:

The database and table name is `templates`, columns are `id` `category` `shortname` `longname` `text`

Comment: Just use https://clipboardjs.com

Comment: Just because the textarea is hidden by either `visibility:hidden` or `display:none` you should still be able to get the `value` using `document.getElementById('copyTarget').value`. Might the problem be somewhere else that we can't see from the given code example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $msg = "";

    $("#copyButton").on("click",function(){

        $msg = $("#copyTarget").text();
        $("#copyTarget").text("");
        $(this).prop({disabled:true});
        $("#pasteButton").removeAttr("disabled");

    })

    $("#pasteButton").on("click",function(){

         $("#pasteTxt").val($msg);
         $(this).prop({disabled:true});
         $("#copyButton").removeAttr("disabled");
        $msg = "";

    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <td>
             <b>PartSelect</b><br />
              <textarea id="copyTarget" cols="25" rows="3">Customer Service&#10;www.partselect.com&#10;888-895-1535</textarea>
            
              <br />
            
              <button id="copyButton">Copy</button>
              <button id="pasteButton" disabled>Paste</button>
            <br><br>
             <input type="text" id="pasteTxt" size="50">
        </td>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $msg = "";

        $("#copyButton").on("click",function(){

            $msg = $("#copyTarget").text();
            $("#copyTarget").text("");
            $(this).prop({disabled:true});
            $("#pasteButton").removeAttr("disabled");

        })

        $("#pasteButton").on("click",function(){

             $("#pasteTxt").val($msg);
             $(this).prop({disabled:true});
             $("#copyButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            $msg = "";

        })

    })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```